# I cannot install 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I have Windows 7 installed on my machine with 297GB HDD.

When I tried to install Ubuntu with WUBI, there's a black screen saying use `(hd 0,0) cannot install wubi`. After restarting the computer, the dual-boot screen appears but and then the same warning again.

I recently have my HDD changed because it wasn't functioning but I use Windows 7 perfectly. Before my hard disk stopped functioning, I was able to download and install Ubuntu with WUBI installer and was using Ubuntu perfectly.

Comment: How are you installing Ubuntu using Wubi?